# Problems with Linear Regresion in Pytorch. NotImplementedError

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

i'm having problems traing to practice the Logistic Regression in pytorch.
I want to use the CIFAR10 dataset but i cant make the training loop because when i can excecute the Linnear function y recived an NotImplementedError

I probably have more than one error that I am not seeing because as I said I am learning.

I leave my code here.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import torch
from torchvision import datasets, transforms
import torch.nn.functional as F
from tqdm import tqdm
import torch.nn as nn

#IMPORTING DATA
datatest = mnist_train = datasets.CIFAR10(root="./datasets",
                                         train=True,
                                         transform=transforms.ToTensor(),
                                         download=True)
datatrain = datasets.CIFAR10(root="./datasets",
                            train=False, 
                            transform=transforms.ToTensor(), 
                            download=True)

print (f'Number of CIFAR test examples {len(datatest)}')
print (f'Number of CIFAR train examples {len(datatest)}')

train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(datatrain, batch_size=100, shuffle=True)
test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(datatest, batch_size=100, shuffle=False)

data_train_iter = iter(train_loader)
images, labels = data_train_iter.next()

print("Shape of the minibatch of images: {}".format(images.shape))
print("Shape of the minibatch of labels: {}".format(labels.shape))

#n_samples, n_features = images.shape, labels.shape
#print(n_samples, n_features)

#MODEL

class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.linear = nn.Linear(3072, 10)

    def foward(self, x):
        return self.linear(x)

#Inicializate model
model = Model()

#Criterion
criterion= nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

#Optimizer
learning_rate = 0.01
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), 
                            lr=learning_rate)
        
# Iterate through train set minibatchs 
for images, labels in tqdm(train_loader):
    # Zero out the gradients
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    
    # Forward pass
    x = images.view(-1, 32*32*3)
    y = model(x)
    loss = criterion(y, labels)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

## Testing
correct = 0
total = len(datatest)

with torch.no_grad():
    # Iterate through test set minibatchs 
    for images, labels in tqdm(test_loader):
        # Forward pass
        x = images.view(-1, 32*32*3)
        y = model(x)
        predictions = torch.argmax(y, dim=1)
        correct += torch.sum((predictions == labels).float())
    
print('Test accuracy: {}'.format(correct/total))
```

Thanks!

Comment: please include the full text of the error!

Answer (score 0):

It is due to a spelling error of `forward` in your `Model` class. You have written it as `foward`. Please correct the spelling in

```
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.linear = nn.Linear(3072, 10)

    def forward(self, x): # You have written it as `foward`
        return self.linear(x)
```